# GeoServer ImageMosaic shx file not created

Tags: ubuntu, shapefile, geoserver, geotiff

I've got a small directory of geotiffs that I'm tring to create an ImageMosaic from in GeoServer 2.19.2 running on Ubuntu 20.04.  The tiffs are on a windows share that the tomcat account has rwx access to (maybe not the wisest, but this is just for testing at the moment). When I create the ImageMosaic, the properties file is created, as is the index shapefile, but without the shx file.  The content of the properties files:

```
#-Automagically created from GeoTools-
#Thu Oct 07 09:22:44 CDT 2021
ExpandToRGB=false
TypeName=test
SuggestedFormat=org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat
Name=test
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
LevelsNum=7
PathType=RELATIVE
Heterogeneous=true
Caching=false
HeterogeneousCRS=false
LocationAttribute=location
Levels=0.2999999999999983,0.3 0.5999562618457467,0.6 1.1997376093294392,1.2 2.3994752186588784,2.399388690779419 4.796153846153819,4.796334012219959 9.592307692307639,9.592668024439918 19.13999999999989,19.146341463414632
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
MosaicCRS=EPSG\:26915
```

I'm guessing this causes further issues down the line, because without knowing that the shx file isn't created, you wouldn't guess anything was wrong during the setup of the ImagMosaic until you try to preview the layer and nothing is shown.  With the possible exception that the calculate bounding box seems incorrect.

[image: Explorer]

[Log](https://pastebin.com/6UK3Ybw2)

Comment: I can't think of any reason why all of the shapefile would be created **except** the `.shx` - can you turn up logging to GEOTOOLS-DEV and try again, then paste the new section of the log file into your question

Comment: Added link to Log

Comment: from the log GeoServer seems happy to be reading `file:/mnt/imagery/CPPJ/Aerials/2004_Photos/subset/subset.shx` but is not able to find `/mnt/imagery/CPPJ/Aerials/2004_Photos/subset/subset.shx` later to write to - I suspect this is to do with your accessing a **windows** shared disk via linux

Comment: If that is the case, then is it a bug with GeoTools?  I can clearly see in the windows share that the shx file is not there (posted screenshot above).  Is the shx file _really_ created or just logged?  If so, why would it seem to get deleted?  I can watch the directory and see the files appear, but an shx file _never_ is.  Unless it happens so fast it never registers in Windows Explorer.

Comment: does it work when you are not using a shared windows drive?

Comment: Yep, just confirmed that.  The .shx file is created and everything works as expected. Unfortunately, that's not an option in production.   The data for all projects is on a windows share.  Again, the tomcat user has 100% access to it.  Why is the .shx file so special in this case?

Comment: I suspect (but can't prove) that windows holds on to the file after reading and thus doesn't let the writer rewrite it and that this process is slower on a shared/network drive. Many people have reported similar issues over the years, but with out access to the hardware it is impossible for the developers to debug let alone fix.

Comment: Interesting, OK.  I guess we'll have to find another solution when it comes to creating ImageMosaics then.  Thanks for the info.  I've go a few more questions about GeoServer that I've written down during the evaluation that I'll be starting new SO questions for.

Comment: Oh, would _manually_ creating the index shapefile allow this process to work?

Comment: No, since GeoServer deletes the old version before writing the new one when creating the mosaic